# Repeat Horizontally the same image on div

Tags: javascript, html, positioning, repeat

Im making a game with javascript, css and html only, it's a simple game, where the character must hit the cakes so you get more points. Im having an issue, on the cakes movement and positioning. I could set them on the screen randomly and going horizontally to the right, but I can't that my function repeats itself nor limit the cakes to a certain zone of the screen.

This is my HTML:

```
<script language ="javascript">

    function createNewCake() {

        var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
                myDiv.id = "cake0";

        myDiv.className = "cake-div";       
        return myDiv;
    }
    function rotateElement(elem, degrees) {

        var rad=degrees*(Math.PI / 180.0);
        var text = "rotate(" + degrees  + "rad)";
        elem.style.transform = text;
        elem.style.webkitTransform = text;
        elem.style.mozTransform = text;
        elem.style.oTransform = text;
        elem.style.msTransform = text;              
    }
var cakes = new Array();

    var colors = new Array();
    colors[0] = "images/bolo1.png";
    colors[1] = "images/bolo2.png";
    colors[2] = "images/bolo3.png";
    colors[3] = "images/maca.png";

    for (var i=0; i<20; i++) {

        var aCake = createNewCake();
        aCake.id = "cake" + i;


        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (colors.length + 1));
        aCake.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + colors[index]+ "')";


        aCake.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth);
        aCake.style.top =  Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight);


        document.body.appendChild(aCake);

        cakes.push(aCake);

    }
    animate();

        function animate() {

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        for (var i=0; i < cakes.length; i++) {
        var pixel = Number(cakes[i].style.left.replace("px",""));
            cakes[i].style.left = pixel + 2 + "px";

        }
    }
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. You want to position them in a certain *zone* of screen? Can you also share a jsFiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

I got it done, thanks all!

It was just if checking if the image pixel is hitting the max width! :D